# Percentage of BTC belong to early adopters

Tags: transactions, blockchain

Are there any statistics that break down the total amount of circulated BTC that is owned by “early adopters”? I know it’s theoretically possible by manually examining the blockchain for unspent transactions that occurred prior to a certain point in time, I’m just wondering if there are any good sources already out there for quick reference

(I know the term “early adopter” is subjective but anything relevant to the theme would be much appreciated.)